# How do I call an Index action and conditionally pass it a value in an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an index action on a controller as follows...

```
public ActionResult Index(string errorMsg = "")
   {
      //do stuff
      ViewBag.ErrorMsg=erorMsg;

      return View();
   }
```

I have another action that is an http post for Index.

When there is something wrong I want to reload the Index page and show the error...

I have my view already conditionally showing errorMsg.  But I cannot figure out how to call Index and pass in the error string?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you'd just share the view between the two actions. I'm guessing you have actions that look something like this (the more info you provide about what index does, the better my example will be):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost()
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Your error message"; // i don't know what your error condition is, so I'm just using a typical example, where the model, which you didn't specify in your question, is valid.
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

And Index.cshtml

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorMsg)) 
 {
      @ViewBag.ErrorMsg
 }

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
 {
     <!-- your form here. I'll just scaffold the editor since I don't know what your view model is -->
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
 }
```

Comment: Given my lack of detail (sorry about that...I was rather in a hurry) you pretty much nailed what I was after.  Thanks for the answer.  Now let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just need to hit the url with the errorMsg in the query string:

`/*controllername*/index?errorMsg=*errormessage*`

However, when there is something wrong you don't necessarily need to reload the page. Seems like you might be approaching this in the wrong way..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectToAction` to redirect to the page, with a querystring for errorMsg value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
    //try to save and then redirect (PRG pattern)
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //Make sure you log the error message for future analysis
    return RedirectToAction("Index",new { errorMs="something"}
  }
}
```

`RedirectToAction` issues a `GET` request. So your form values will be gone, because **HTTP is stateless**. If you want to keep the form values as it is in the form, return the posted viewmodel object again. I would get rid of ViewBag and add a new property called `ErrorMsg` to my ViewModel and set the value of that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
    //try to save and then redirect (PRG pattern)
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //Make sure you log the error message for future analysis
    model.ErrorMsg="some error";
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

and in the view you can check this model property and show the message to user.